# SpringBoot - Switch jackson reference on many-to one-relationship

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, one-to-many

I have a springboot app which is working well. In it, I have 2 entities, Project and Affectation, with a many-to-one relationship. One projet can have many affectation, but one affectation can have only one project. I set up `@JsonBackReference` on the "many" one and `@JsonManagedReference` on the lonely one. GET / POST request works well.

**Problem:**

Currently, when I get a Project, I receive the affectations which are linked to that project, and when I get an affectation, I have no informations about the linked project.

***I would like to inverse it.*** I want that when I get an affectation, I receive the linked project. To do it, I switched `@jsonBackReference` and the `@JsonManagedReference`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Projet")
public class Projet{
...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project")
    @JsonBackReference (value="project-affectation")
    @Cascade(value = { CascadeType.DELETE, CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE })
    private Set<Affectation> affectations = new HashSet<Affectation>();
...
}



@Entity
@Table(name="Affectation")
public class Affectation{
...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn (name="projectid")
    @JsonManagedReference (value="project-affectation")
    private Project project;
...
}
```

With this code, GET request is fine and I receive what I want. But POST a project doesn't work anymore:

> Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.open.chargeplan.entities.Project]]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not handle managed/back reference 'project-affectation': back reference type (java.util.Set) not compatible with managed type (com.open.chargeplan.entities.Affectation)

This is how I POST in projectController.java:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, path="/add")
public ProjectResponse addNewProjet(@RequestBody Project project){
    projetRepository.save(project);
    return new ProjectResponse(ProjectResponse.Status.OK, project);
}
```

and this is what I am trying to post:

> curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"projectid":
>   "7A93154537", "name": "projectTest", "customer": "customerTest",
>   "description": "this is a test"}' http://localhost:8081/project/add

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: What are you `POST`ing?

Comment: @AnilBhaskar I updated my question

Comment: @AnilBhaskar my bad, I misunderstand your request, I updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it solved by removing `@JsonManagedReference` BUT keep `@JsonBackReference`.